# Writing a test for a web application

Tags: python, testing, pytest, bottle

I am writing a web application while learning, I have written a function which receives a file. now I want to write a test function for it.i am using pytest.

in the test function, i will be required to submit a file, I have already checked [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file) for doing so but i am not getting it. please show some light so i can create a test function for the following given function.

```
@app.post('/check/<number>')
def file_upload(number):
    u_name = request.forms.get('username')  # accepting username
    time = datetime.datetime.now()
    # type(uploaded) == <class 'bytes'>
    uploaded = request.files.get('upload').file.read()  # uploaded outputs by user
    expected = questions[number].output
    expected = expected.strip()
    uploaded = uploaded.strip()
    ans = (uploaded == expected)
    usernames[u_name].append(Submission(question=number, time=time,
                                        output=uploaded, result=ans))
    if not ans:
        return 'Wrong answer'
    else:
        return 'Solved! Great Job!'
```

I want `200` response while running the test file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [WebTest](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/webtest/en/latest/):

```
from webtest import TestApp

test_app = TestApp(app)
resp = test_app.post('/check/123')  # by default, this fails if your app returns anything except HTTP 2XX
```

Some other examples from Stack Overflow:

[Test bottle app without running bottle server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37885638/test-bottle-app-without-running-bottle-server)

[Unit testing Bottle app with WebTest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30969259/unit-testing-bottle-app-with-webtest/31569576)